# TextBox malfunctioning on style

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm using the following style on my wpf `TextBox`.

```
 <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="DarkGray" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,22,0"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

On using this style the textbox stops working. If i click on the textbox the mouse pointer disappears, no focus or text appears. What is wrong with this style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your scrollbox, and it will work

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,22,0"/>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Xaml did not provide a place for interaction with the keyboard/mouse.  I'm not alltogether sure what you are trying to design, but if you place a TextBox inside your ScrollViewer, your template will stop exhibiting the 'malfunction' you are describing...

```
<Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Margin="0,0,22,0" Padding="5,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

This snippet shows a modification to your Xaml where the ScrollViewer contains a TextBox.  The MouseDown event sets focus on the control, and keyboard interaction occurs as expected.